# How to integrate my React.js app to an Odoo module?

Tags: reactjs, xml, module, interface, odoo

I build a React js app using Vite and I want this app to be the interface of an Odoo module.
Notice that I have the paid version of Odoo.
How can I do that, and how to know the api that I need to communicate with the database?
I didn't find any information on the Internet that will help me to do that.

I tried to add the content of the dist folder to the static folder inside my module files but I didn't know how to connect between the xml file and my index.html file that will render the React app.

Answer (score 1):

For Integration of Odoo you use following methods:

1. External API - Ref [Web Service - Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/howtos/web_services.html)
2. Supported Language's Framework to utilize - Current Odoo External Apis are supporting in Python, Java, Go and Ruby. - Ref [External Api - Odoo Documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/external_api.html)
3. Using Modules of Odoo for Exposing Restful API - From [Odoo App Store](https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/browse?search=API)

In conculsion, you might require the expertise of a developer who understands both Odoo and the technology you are integrating it.